# Fourier series expansion of Dirac delta function

Tags: fourier-series, dirac-delta

My question is from Arfken & Weber (Ed. 7) 19.2.2:

In the first part, the question asks for Fourier series expansion of $\delta(x)$. I have found $$\delta(x)=1/2\pi + 1/\pi\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \cos(nx)$$ Then by using the identity
$$\sum^{N}_{n=1} \cos(nx)=\frac{\sin(Nx/2)}{\sin(x/2)}\cos\left[\left(N+\frac{1}{2}\right)\frac{x}{2}\right]$$, we need to find a Fourier representation which is consistent with $$\delta(x-t)=\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\phi^{*}_{n}(t)\phi_{n}(x)$$. I have tried expanding the trigonometric functions with exponential terms countless times, however could not obtain a sufficient result. Any help is appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: Here $\delta(x)$ is the $2\pi$-periodic Dirac delta **distribution**. $\delta(x)=1/2\pi + 1/\pi\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} cos(nx)$ is true only in the sense of distributions, that is for any $f \in C^\infty$ and $2\pi$-periodic : $f(0) = \int_{-\pi}^\pi  \delta(x)f(x)dx = \lim_{N \to \infty} \int_{-\pi}^\pi (1/2\pi+1/\pi\sum^{N}_{n=1} cos(nx))f(x)dx$ which is no more than the Fourier series main theorem.

Comment: I don't see what you mean with $\delta(x-t)=\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\phi^{*}_{n}(t)\phi_{n}(x)$. Note that (again in the sense of distributions) $\delta(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty e^{i n x}$ and $$\delta(x-t) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty e^{-int} e^{i n x}$$ where $e^{-int}$ are the Fourier coefficients of the distribution $S(x) = \delta(x-t)$ is it what you want ?

Comment: @ user1952009 This identity is also given in the book (Eq. 5.27). Considering $\phi_{n}$ to be orthonormal with unit weight  on interval (a,b), the expansion is $$\delta(x-t)=\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}c_{n}(t)\phi_{n}(x)$$, where $$c_{n}(t)=\int^{b}_{a}\phi^{*}(x)\delta(x-t)dx=\phi^{*}_{n}(t)$$. Finally we get $$\delta(x-t)=\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\phi^{*}_{n}(t)\phi_{n}(x)$$

Comment: Here the orthonormal basis of $L^2([-\pi,\pi])$ is $\phi_n(x) = \frac{e^{inx}}{\sqrt{x}}$ and $c_n(t) = \frac{e^{int}}{2\pi}=\phi_n(t)$. But $\delta$ is not in $L^2$ so we need more work to show that **in the sense of distributions** $\delta(x-t) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \overline{c_n(t)} \phi_n(x)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \overline{\phi_n(t)} \phi_n(x)$. With the $\frac{1}{2\pi},\frac{\cos(nt)}{\pi}, \frac{\sin(nt)}{\pi}$ orthonormal basis it works the same way. Do you understand all this ?

Answer (score 1):

It is not toooo difficult to talk precisely about convergence of Fourier series of distributions, although certainly pointwise (or $L^2$) convergence is "out the window". And we needn't go so far as to just ask for weak-*-convergence, although that's fine, too: we can easily talk about convergence in $L^2$-Sobolev spaces on products $\mathbb T^n$ of circles $\mathbb T$.

For example, on $\mathbb T^2$, for real $s$, $H^s$ is (for example) the completion of the space of finite sums $\sum_{m,n}c_{m,n}\,e^{2\pi i(mx+ny)}$ with respect to the Sobolev norm whose square is
$$
\Big|\sum_{m,n}|c_{m,n}\,e^{2\pi i(mx+ny)}\Big|^2_{H^s}
\;=\; \sum_{m,n} |c_{m,n}|^2\cdot (1+m^2+n^2)^s
$$
The Sobolev imbedding theorem proves that $H^\infty=\bigcap_s H^s= C^\infty$, so $H^{-\infty}=\bigcup H^s$ is all distributions on $\mathbb T^2$.

The question asks for the Fourier expansion of the "integrate along the diagonal" distribution. Since it is compactly-supported on $\mathbb T^2$, we correctly compute the coefficients by applying the distribution to the smooth functions $(x,y)\to e^{2\pi i(mx+ny)}$, by integrating along the diagonal. Thus, the $m,n$-th coefficient is $0$ unless $m=n$, in which case it is $1$. The resulting Fourier series converges in the Hilbert space $H^{1+\varepsilon}$ for every $\varepsilon>0$, by direct computation.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem you can utilize the *resolution of the identity* [1]. As explained in [1], take a complete orthonormal basis set of functions $\left\{\phi_n\right\}$.

For example, for the domain $x\in[0,2\pi)$, take
$$\left\{\phi_n\right\} = \left\{ 
\frac{
a_m\cos{\left(m\,x\right)}
+
b_m\sin{\left(m\,x\right)}
}
{
\sqrt{ 
2\,\pi \left|a_m\right|^2   \,\delta_{m,0}
+
\pi \left(\left|a_m\right|^2 + \left|b_m\right|^2\right) \left(1-\delta_{m,0}\right)
}
}
\mid
m=0,1,2,\ldots
\right\} .$$
Again, as explained in [1], from the *resolution of the identity* you have that
$$
\delta(x-t) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty  \varphi_n (x)\, \varphi_n^*(t). $$
Specifically, with the basis set of functions above, we have that
$$
\delta(x-t) = \sum_{m=0}^\infty  
\frac{
\left[
a_m\cos{\left(m\,x\right)}
+
b_m\sin{\left(m\,x\right)}
\right]\left[
a_m^*\cos{\left(m\,t\right)}
+
b_m^*\sin{\left(m\,t\right)}
\right]
}
{
{ 
2\,\pi \left|a_m\right|^2   \,\delta_{m,0}
+
\pi \left(\left|a_m\right|^2 + \left|b_m\right|^2\right) \left(1-\delta_{m,0}\right)
}
}
. $$

As another example, for the domain $x\in[0,2\pi)$, take
$$\left\{\phi_n\right\} = \left\{ 
\frac{
\exp{\left(+i\,m\,x\right)}
}
{
\sqrt{ 2\,\pi}
}
\mid
m=\ldots,-2,-1,0,1,2,\ldots
\right\} .$$
Again, as explained in [1], from the *resolution of the identity* you have that
$$
\delta(x-t) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty  \varphi_n (x)\, \varphi_n^*(t). $$
Specifically, with the basis set of functions above, we have that
$$
\delta(x-t) = \sum_{m=-\infty}^\infty  
\frac{
\exp{\left(+i\,m\,x\right)}
\,
\exp{\left(-i\,m\,t\right)}
}
{
2\,\pi  
}
. $$

**Bibliography**

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function